# Topology exercises

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest a collection of (solved) exercises in topology? Undergrad level, as a companion to Dugundji's Topology (although excellent it doesn't provide the solutions to the problems).

Thanks.

Comment: _Introduction to Topology_ by Gamelin and Greene contains about 40 pages of solutions to selected exercises.

Comment: +1, I am quite interested in this as well!

Comment: @Learner Since you have created the tag ([tag:exercises-and-solutions]), I wanted to inform you that I have made a post on meta which is related to this tag: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/rename-exercises-and-solutions-tag-or-completely-remove-it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Elementary Topology Problem Textbook
O. Ya. Viro, O. A. Ivanov,
N. Yu. Netsvetaev, V. M. Kharlamov, is available freely online at

- http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/eng-book-nopfs.pdf

This book is published by **AMS** and that comes with solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 7):

"Fundamentals of General Topology: Problems and Exercises" by A. V. Arkhangel'skii; V.I. Ponomarev is a fun book, though it might be hard to find and the level might be higher than you'd like.

Comment: great book! Nice intro to the Russian school of general topology, and as such more set-theoretical in nature than the more (IMHO) geometric Dugundji approach. They consider different types of problems.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend ["Elementary Topology Problem Textbook"](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dluu/ps/Viro,%20Ivanov,%20Kharlamov%20and%20Netsvetaev%20-%20Topology%20with%20problems%20and%20solutions.pdf) by Viro, Ivanov, Netsvetaev, Kharlamov.