# Is there a book on **Topology** with the desired properties

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have completed courses in *Real Analysis,Abstract Algebra,Linear Algebra*.

My next topic is **Topology and Metric Spaces**. I am searching for books in this book..Until today I have used the following books 
:

- Real Analysis- Bartle,Sherbert
- Abstract Algebra-J.B.Fraleigh
- Linear Algebra-Friedberg,Spence

All these books are easy to read and most importantly had solutions behind them and so it was very easy for me to check my solutions to the given exercises.

I searched the web and it gave back the book **Munkres**. But the fact is that the exercises do not contain enough hints to start and I can't verify whether my solution is correct/not?

Are there any alternative books in this subject which are detailed, contain many examples and exercises which are good and at least have a outline how to solve them.

Any help.

Comment: [Schaum's Outline of General Topology](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-General-Topology-Outlines/dp/0071763473)? (I haven't looked at it myself but I've heard good things about Schaum's Outlines in general.

Comment: Have a look at the book recommendations in this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology).

Comment: Some related posts: 
[Topology exercises](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/27629),
[Topology Exercises Books](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/612851), 
[Topology textbook with a solution manual](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Topology of Metric Spaces* by S.Kumaresan would be a nice choice. It contains a good number of problems and provides sufficient hints to solve them too. The author uses Geometry often to make the reader visualize the stuff.

On the other hand *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* by George.F.Simmons was also used by me as a reference for many concepts in Topology as a beginner.

Good luck!